# Wrong value printed when implementing chaining methods

Tags: c++, named-parameters

I am given a specific main

```
int main() {

  Widget w;

  w.set(3).print().set(2).print();

  w.print();
}
```

and I am required to write a class Widget such that the program prints 3,2,2.

my best attempt sofar prints a disappointing 3,2,3 :/

```
class Widget{
public:
  Widget(){m_i =0;};

  Widget(int i){m_i =i;};

  Widget set(int i){
    this->m_i = i;
    return *this;
    };

  Widget print(){
    std::cout<<this->m_i<<std::endl;
    return *this;
    };
  int m_i;
};

int main() {

  Widget w;

  w.set(3).print().set(2).print();

  w.print();
}
```

any idea on how to solve this?
Thanks to everyone who is willing to give some advice :)

Comment: You copy the widget on each operation. That's bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is that the object returned from your functions needs to be a reference e.g. a `Widget&`, not a `Widget`. Currently, you're returning a whole new copy from each set() or print() call, which means that any further changes to that object are never applied to the original `w` object.

Comment: thanks a lot ... I thought the problem with using references instead of objects was only related to arguments of function, not with returned objects :)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you leave the original `w` unchanged after the first call to `set`.

I happens because you copy `w` on each return of each operation:

```
Widget set(int i){
    this->m_i = i;
    return *this; // Copy, return type is a `Widget` value
}
```

You should instead return by reference:

```
//    v--- There
Widget& set(int i){
    this->m_i = i;
    return *this; // No copy, return type is a `Widget` reference
}
```

Not copying the widget variable will cause `w` to be mutated instead of temporary copies.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing: Both `set` and `print` should return `*this` by reference. Adding that in (replacing `Widget` with `Widget&`) and some other minor fixes do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>

class Widget{
public:
  Widget(int m) // Initialization over assignment
  : m_i(m)
  { }

  Widget()      // Initialization over assignment
  : m_i(0)
  { }

  Widget& set(int i) // return a reference 
  {
    m_i = i;         // this-> is not recommended
    return *this;
  };

  Widget& print()    // return a reference 
  {
    std::cout<< m_i << std::endl; // this-> is not recommended
    return *this;
  };

private: // data members are usually private
  int m_i;
};

int main() {

  Widget w;
  w.set(3).print().set(2).print().print();

  return 0;
}
```

But realistically you would declare `print` as a const function, because it makes sense to be able to print a const object